# SSRS Lookup function of two columns within the same dataset

Tags: reporting-services, lookup

I need an SSRS Lookup query to get results from Dataset 2 Column1 and if not found in Column1 lookup Column2.

Dataset1 - WONUMBER

Dataset2 - WONUMBER, Column1, Column2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use an IIF() in your return argument of the LOOKUP function like this

```
=LOOKUP(Fields!WONUMBER.Value,
        Fields!WONUMBER.Value, 
        IIF(Fields!Column1.Value=Nothing,Fields!Column2.Value,Fields!Column1.Value),
        "DataSet2"
       )
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I needed! I have one more question. I need to hide the rows from the report based on that lookup expression (basically values that CONTAINS something in that expression). Lets say hid lookup values which contains T0W. Thank you in advance for help in this matter.

Comment: Glad to help. You will need to create a new question. SO has strict rules about asking multiple questions, it's to help others find answers to specific questions.